# emacs regexp replace 11 with "11"

Tags: emacs

I have a bunch of C integer array initialisation code, e.g.

```
int a[] = {11,22,33,44};
```

that I would like to change to strings, e.g.

```
char *a[] = {"11","22","33","44"};
```

Is there a reg exp I can use to do this? e.g.

```
M-x replace-regexp RET
Replace regexp: [0-9] RET
Replace regexp with: "[0-9]" RET
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp
Query replace regexp: \([0-9]+\)
Query replace regexp \([0-9]+\) with: "\1"
```

`[0-9]+` matches one or more consecutive digits.  The escaped parentheses, `\(` and `\)`, make the contents a group.  The `\1` in the replacement string is replaced with whatever was matched between the first set of escaped parentheses in the query.

*Thanks to [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) for the reminder in the comments that you can usually use `C-M-%` for `query-replace-regexp`.*

Comment: is that a cut and paste error? the + means mutliple occurences? \1 must mean the value of the matched string?

Comment: And `query-replace-regexp` is usualy bound to `C-M-%`.

Comment: brilliant! reg exps are super intimidating and tricky syntactically - you've saved a heap of frustration...

Comment: @Hiett: Indeed - for me (under X, rather than in a terminal) the following works: hold down Ctrl, hold down Alt, hold down Shift, press 5 and then release all the modifiers.  That's why I typically just do `M-x` `query-replace-regexp`, using tab completion...